# AutoMapper: class properties, map ISet<object> to HashSet<Object>

Tags: c#, automapper-3, automapper-6

I have defined a mapping to/from my DTO object, the properties on one versus the other match excatly except that the DTO Object has collections defined as ISet  and the non DTO object has those collectiond defined as HashSet .  I've noticed a significant performance hit mapping from DTO -> Non DTO, vs the other way.

AutoMapper seems to have trouble going from Interface from concrete class, I'm wondering if I'm missing something in a mapping, or configuration somewhere to be more explicit.  This paradigm exists across our code base, but for my object in question I can map 2k objects **from** the DTO in about 8 seconds, and I can map the exact same objects **to** the DTO in about .1 seconds

```
class ExampleDTO
{
    public int Id;
    public enum Type;
    public DateTime creationTime;
    public ISet<string> StringThings;
    public ISet<int> IntThings;
    public ISet<double> DoubleThings;
}
class Example
{
    public int Id;
    public enum Type;
    public DateTime creationTime;
    public HashSet<string> StringThings;
    public HashSet<int> IntThings;
    public HashSet<double> DoubleThings;
}
```

Mapping:

```
CreateMap<ExampleDTO, Example>();
CreateMap<Example, ExampleDTO>();
```

Comment: To Further test to make sure our code base wasn't causing trouble, I created a test using the above objects, and found that the ExampleDTO->Example mapping occured in ~11.5 seconds, and the reverse took 2.29 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found that upgrading Automapper (to version 6.0.2) would be the way to go in our case.  Using the updated AutoMapper and the same objects and mappings listed above we saw the ExampleDTO->Example object mapped in 1.57 seconds, and the reverse case mapped in 1.86 seconds.  I'm not overly happy posting an answer that says use the upgrade, so I'll post a few options that gave some modest gains, and if anyone else has an actual answer, I'll gladly mark that one.

I tried creating a mapping for the ISet HashSet and this was about twice as fast as without that specified mapping, I cannot remember *exactly* what I did here, but I found it on the googles.

The other option I tried, was creating Non Mappable HashSets on the DTO object that simply returned the ISet.  This was about 3x faster, but still not close to the performance gained by upgrading.

```
class ExampleDTO
{
    public int Id;
    public enum Type;
    public DateTime creationTime;
    public ISet<string> StringThings;
    [IgnoreMap]
    public HashSet<string> StringThingsHash
    {
        get
        {
            return StringThings;
        }
    }
    public ISet<int> IntThings;
    [IgnoreMap]
    public HashSet<int> IntThingsHash
    {
        get
        {
            return IntThings;
        }
    }
    public ISet<double> DoubleThings;
    [IgnoreMap]
    public HashSet<double> DoubleThingsHash
    {
        get
        {
            return DoubleThings;
        }
    }
```

and I used the following mapping

```
CreateMap<ExampleDTO, Example>()
  .ForMember(dest => dest.StringThings, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.StringThingsHash)
  .ForMember(dest => dest.IntThings, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.IntThingsHash)
  .ForMember(dest => dest.DoubleThings, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.DoubleThingsHash);
CreateMap<Example, ExampleDTO>();
```